# How to use the WP REST API for new user registration (sign up form)?

Tags: rest-api, user-meta, user-registration

Is it possible to create a sign up form that can work through WP REST API for visitors to be able to create accounts on my site?

I can create such a form and use it to create new users. This works with wp_rest nonce when I am logged in as administrator.

But if there is a visitor which is not logged in, the same form does not work of course. I think this is a question of authentication. Can you suggest a general idea how this can work? How can I allow visitors to be able to sign up with REST API?

Answer (score 7):

hopefully you've found the answer already. Here's our solution, for your reference. :D

The following code should add User Registration via REST API to your WordPress Website. It supports Registration of 'subscriber' and 'customer'.

Add it to your function.php

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'wp_rest_user_endpoints');
/**
 * Register a new user
 *
 * @param  WP_REST_Request $request Full details about the request.
 * @return array $args.
 **/
function wp_rest_user_endpoints($request) {
  /**
   * Handle Register User request.
   */
  register_rest_route('wp/v2', 'users/register', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'wc_rest_user_endpoint_handler',
  ));
}
function wc_rest_user_endpoint_handler($request = null) {
  $response = array();
  $parameters = $request->get_json_params();
  $username = sanitize_text_field($parameters['username']);
  $email = sanitize_text_field($parameters['email']);
  $password = sanitize_text_field($parameters['password']);
  // $role = sanitize_text_field($parameters['role']);
  $error = new WP_Error();
  if (empty($username)) {
    $error->add(400, __("Username field 'username' is required.", 'wp-rest-user'), array('status' => 400));
    return $error;
  }
  if (empty($email)) {
    $error->add(401, __("Email field 'email' is required.", 'wp-rest-user'), array('status' => 400));
    return $error;
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    $error->add(404, __("Password field 'password' is required.", 'wp-rest-user'), array('status' => 400));
    return $error;
  }
  // if (empty($role)) {
  //  $role = 'subscriber';
  // } else {
  //     if ($GLOBALS['wp_roles']->is_role($role)) {
  //      // Silence is gold
  //     } else {
  //    $error->add(405, __("Role field 'role' is not a valid. Check your User Roles from Dashboard.", 'wp_rest_user'), array('status' => 400));
  //    return $error;
  //     }
  // }
  $user_id = username_exists($username);
  if (!$user_id && email_exists($email) == false) {
    $user_id = wp_create_user($username, $password, $email);
    if (!is_wp_error($user_id)) {
      // Ger User Meta Data (Sensitive, Password included. DO NOT pass to front end.)
      $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
      // $user->set_role($role);
      $user->set_role('subscriber');
      // WooCommerce specific code
      if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
        $user->set_role('customer');
      }
      // Ger User Data (Non-Sensitive, Pass to front end.)
      $response['code'] = 200;
      $response['message'] = __("User '" . $username . "' Registration was Successful", "wp-rest-user");
    } else {
      return $user_id;
    }
  } else {
    $error->add(406, __("Email already exists, please try 'Reset Password'", 'wp-rest-user'), array('status' => 400));
    return $error;
  }
  return new WP_REST_Response($response, 123);
}
```

IMHO, a more better way would to include the additional function as a seperate plugin. So even when your user changed theme, your api calls won't be affected.

Therefore I've developed a **plugin** for User Registration via REST API in WordPress. Better yet, it supports creating 'customer' for WooCommerce too!

[WP REST User](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-user/), check it out if you want.

Comment: Hey dude, thank you so so much! it really works

Comment: user-created fine but return response showing error

Comment: Take note that this hook does not respect the membership setting. You can add `get_option('users_can_register')` to do so.

Comment: I can't download the plugin. Can I use it for wp 6.1

Comment: Is this a secure way to send a password? What would an example request look like?

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own signup routine using `wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-users-controller.php` (WP v4.7.4) as a reference implementation.  You could also modify the WordPress version by doing something like the following:

```
function nLbwuEa8_modify_create_user_route() {
    $users_controller = new WP_REST_Users_Controller();

    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', '/users', array(
        array(
            'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
            'callback'            => array($users_controller, 'create_item'),
            'permission_callback' => function( $request ) {

                // METHOD 1: Silently force the role to be a subscriber
                // $request->set_param('roles', array('subscriber'));

                // METHOD 2: Be nice and provide an error message
                if ( ! current_user_can( 'create_users' ) && $request['roles'] !== array('subscriber')) {

                    return new WP_Error(
                        'rest_cannot_create_user',
                        __( 'Sorry, you are only allowed to create new users with the subscriber role.' ),
                        array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() )
                    );

                }

                return true;
            },
            'args'                => $users_controller->get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema( WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE ),
        ),
    ) );

} );
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'nLbwuEa8_modify_create_user_route' );
```

The important parts being the `permission_callback` key (where you are essentially disabling authentication).  And the `args` key that could be used to add a captcha so spammers don't overrun the service.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Enabling the ability for arbitrary people to create users is not really safe. They can simply create themselves an Admin level user and take over your site. You should instead use the registration flow, which does not presently have an API call for it. Send them to the wp-login.php?action=register page and let them create an account there.

Comment: @Otto I was trying to show a proof of concept not the exact implementation.  It's been a while since I looked at this but how would it be different from wp-login.php?action=register if the only type of user you could create was a "subscriber" if you are not authenticated?  Can I make that clearer in my post?

Comment: The Rest API route allows you to create users of any role, not just subscribers. Although, it does have a check to prevent role promotion, so that might be acceptable. You'd want to test that you couldn't, for example, just make an Admin level user.

Comment: @Otto Do you feel like this is a better solution?

Comment: Nope. It might work, it might not. I have not tested it in any way.

Comment: @Otto I have tested it and it works.  Since you're so dead set against this solution perhaps you should offer a solution *to the original problem*.

Comment: My concerns are simply based on security. Creating users is potentially dangerous, so such a solution should be tested properly before being recommended. If it works correctly, then that's great. I've just never seen anybody make a change like this to the REST API before, so there are some valid concerns to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom route for your site that collects the fields you need and then calls the internal wp_insert_user() function.  This way you'd be able to validate the information the user is providing, including restricting which role they're allowed to get.  I'd also be tempted to limit the # of users that can be created by the same IP address in a day, or something like that.

Comment: Custom route documentation: http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a plugin called [WP Webhooks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-webhooks/) that can do this.

According to the plugin page:

It allows you to trigger actions (such as creating a user or a post) in WordPress upon receiving data from other services.

Many form solutions work with Zapier (including Gravity Forms, JotForm, Formidable, and even Google Forms) so one of these could be used to trigger a new user signup using this method.

Wordpress is already has [native Zapier support](https://zapier.com/apps/wordpress/integrations) without this plugin, but creating a new user is not a supported action using the native WordPress Zapier app.

Answer (score -1):

Try [WP REST User](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-user/) it has create user and reset password functionality