# New user signup via REST API

Tags: rest-api, user-registration

The following question has some answers that give custom code for new user sign up via the REST API: [How to use the WP REST API for new user registration (sign up form)?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/264866/219606)

As of version 5.9 the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#create-a-user) seems to indicate that this functionality is included.

Are the answers to the above question still relevant or have they been superceded by the built in functionality?